# TagHelper not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a tag helper which seems to be half way working?
I am able to set a breakpoint inside the process override and it'll hit it. However, the setting of the `htmlContent` seems to not show.

Breakpoint hit:
[image]

_ViewImports.cshtml

```cs
@using Gradebook      
@addTagHelper *, Gradebook
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

TextBoxInputHelper.cs

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace Gradebook.TagHelpers
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime package into your project
    [HtmlTargetElement("TextBoxInput")]
    public class TextBoxInputHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Editable { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; } = "Control1";
        public string HelpLabel { get; set; }
        public bool Required { get; set; }
        public string ErrorText { get; set; }
        public string ValidText { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression Model { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "TextBoxInput";

            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("text", Text);

            var id = GetControlId();

            var requiredHtml = Required ? "required" : "";
            var errorHtml = EmptyOrUse(ErrorText,$"<div class='invalid-feedback'>{ErrorText}</div>");
            var validHtml = EmptyOrUse(ValidText,$"<div class='valid-feedback'>{ValidText}</div>");
            

            var html = $@"
                <div class='col-md-4 mb-3'>
                    <label for='{id}'>{Label}</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='{id}' placeholder='{HelpLabel}' value='{Text}' {requiredHtml}>
                    {errorHtml}                   
                    {validHtml}
                </div>
                ";

            var builder = new HtmlContentBuilder();
            builder.SetHtmlContent(html);


            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(builder);

        }

        private string EmptyOrUse(string value, string formatted) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? string.Empty : formatted;

        private string GetControlId()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id)) return Id;

            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model?.Name) 
                ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) 
                    ? "" 
                    : Name 
                : Model.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

cshtml view using the tag

```html
<h2>title</h2>
<form>
    <TextBoxInput name="User.LastName" Text="@Model.User.LastName" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please share how the taghelper is being applied in your view.

Comment: I've updated the post to include my using

Comment: Try non-selfclosing variant: `<TextBoxInput name="User.LastName" Text="@Model.User.LastName"></TextBoxInput>`

Comment: @pfx that worked! Thank you! I was not aware that it would be sensitive to that.